# Edit a file outside the web root

Tags: php, python, cgi

I have developed a python desktop application and application itself having setup page to change some configurations in the application and it is saved as a configuration file.

Now I need do to give web interface to change those configurations by using web browser remotely. But I need to change the same configuration file.

I can’t access any file outside the web root, So My first question is how can I edit that file which is located outside the web root.

more info : for web application I use LAMP stack and desktop application is python based.

someone suggest me to use CGI, Second question : Is that possible, if it is possible how I can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: thanks, I checked that and it wouldn't help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably by bind mounts (assuming Linux), so that the file is in it's original location as well as in the web root.

Or by priviledge separation. The web root sends a query to some worker job, that has access to all the needed files.

Comment: I got the first option, but i didn't get the second one. Can you direct me to somewhere I can get more info about that or just explain little more. thanks

Comment: Okay, priviledge separation is a way where you have one frontend (e.g. your webserver) facing the hostile world. That process has almost no proviledges, just those really needed to do his job. When some job has to be done that needs more priviledges, the "inferior" process tells the "mighty" process what to do. The interface between those two processes could be a network socket, or DBUS, or whatever. Basically, you'd write a separate file-system-writer process that communicates with your web-application.

Comment: Can you please suggest any particular technology for "separate file-system-writer process that communicates with your web-application" ?

Comment: No, whatever suits you and fit's to your skills and operating system. I personally would use Python and DBUS. But if you're a perl or ruby guy, go for that. And if you're using Windows, then use what's there. I personally would however **not** use PHP, it had too many security issues in the last 10 years. If you ever worked with Perl, then look up the concept of "tainted" variables and how to untaint them, i.E. checking if they contain just sensible data via regular expressions. Python/Ruby don't support tainted vars, but you can use the same idea in the "mighty" process: check everything!